# Webdriver/Xpath/Java: Crawl DOM to click on 'Element with No Unique Identifier'

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I am trying to find and click 'Available' seats from a Travel website Seat Layout. Challenge is, the available Seat has no Unique Identifier whereas 'Blocked' (already booked) seat has one  in the form of 'title' (Please refer HTML). How we make WebDriver skip any blocked seat and click any 'Available' seat on any random occurrence of seat layout (Pic)??

[image: SeatLayout]

HTML shows structure of 2 Blocked Seats (L2 , L4) and one available seat in between (L3)

```
    <div style="max-width:695px;">
<div class="GXXXXXXX" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="GXXXXXXX">
<div class="GXXXXXXX"> </div>
<div class="GXXXXXXX">
<table>
<colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
Blocked Seat
<div class="GDXXXXXX GDXXXXX0" style="overflow:hidden;position:static;margin: 0 5px 5px 0;" title="Seat Name: L2 | Fare: Rs. 300.0">L2</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>
Available Seat
<div class="GXXXXXX GXXXXXX0" style="overflow:hidden;position:static;margin: 0 5px 5px 0;">L3</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
Blocked Seat
<div class="GXXXXXX GXXXXXXX" style="overflow:hidden;position:static;margin: 0 5px 5px 0;" title="Seat Name: L4 | Fare: Rs. 300.0">L4</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the logic. See if the DIV has title attribute. If it does not have the seat is available. Change the logic as per your need.

```
List<WebElement> seats = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.GXXXXXX.GXXXXXXX"));

for (WebElement seat : seats) {
   if(seat.getAttribute("title") != null){
        System.out.println("Seat is not available");
   }else{
        System.out.println("Seat is available");
        seat.click(); // break the loop if you wish
   }                    
}
```

Comment: The Logic worked after some Modification , but It clicks to 'All Available seats'. How do we restrict it to Click the only one available seat . Code:: List<WebElement> seats = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[xx]"));
       for (WebElement seat : seats) {          if(seat.getAttribute("title").startsWith("Seat Name:")){
               System.out.println("Seat is not available");              
          }else{
               System.out.println("Seat is available");               seat.click();
                // break the loop if you wish
          }                    
       }

Comment: As I mentioned in comment, you have to break the loop by using "break" statement"